Spotlight not returning results for internal iMac drives - ".Spotlight-V100" folder has red forbidden sign
My iMac running [macOS High Sierra][2] has two SSD drives: 256GB with the OS on it and 2TB for data.
Spotlight returns zero results when doing a search on both drives. Also other apps using Spotlight for searching (for example the Calendar app and Outlook 2016) return no results when doing a search.
However, searching an external connected USB drive works perfectly, and also searching a shared remote network drive gives perfect search results!
I ran these commands to trigger a reindex:
sudo mdutil -a -i off 
sudo rm -rf /.Spotlight-v100

and restarted the computer, but that didn't solve my problem:
Looking in Finder, I see the root .Spotlight-V100 folder with a red "forbidden" sign. Is this normal?
Log generated by a Spotlight Search Test in Mints :

Welcome to Ask Different. How did you trigger the Spotlight reindex?

/.Spotlight-V100 only being accessible by System/root is correct, and not related to the issue you are seeing.

@jaume : in Terminal i did the following
sudo mdutil -a -i off
sudo rm -rf /.Spotlight-v100 (did that for both volumes then checked in Finder and the indexes were really deleted)
restarted the computer
then checked Activity Monitor where mds and mdworks(s) were 'red hot' for couple of hours.
In both volumes i have new .Spotlight-v100 folders
But still zero results when doing whatever search with Spotlight.

Thank you, could you try the commands posted in this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/292631/spotlight-completely-broken?rq=1?

Thank you jaume !  I executed the commands as described in the link you sent (see my added screenshot). Now in Activity Monitor, mds and mdworker(s) are again active using %CPU. I will wait a couple of hours and then do a new search test on local volumes (FYI : remote volumes, external USB or on network work perfect with Spotlight.... seems like the local volumes are kind of hidden for Spotlight ... permissions ? ... )

Seems i can't add new screenshot in comments ...

Asking because you haven't mentioned it: If you haven't done this already, there would be two things to check in System Settings for Spotlight: 1) see which categories are checked in the main Spotlight panel; and especially 2) click the "Search Privacy..." button and make sure your two SSDs are not listed there.

@Bruce Van Allen : ALL Categories are checked in main Spotlight panel and Search Privacy is EMPTY.

In the meantime, i found following : after doing first sudo -a -i /off and sudo -a -i /on then wait about 20-30 minutes, Spotlight starts working again on volumes ONLY. In Finder, searching files and folders works (top right search-box). Still ZERO results when searching for example in Calendar or Outlook, there nothing. And then, 6 hours later, Spotlight gives up, and even in Finder again zero results. Really strange behavior ...

UPDATE : i don't even have to wait 20-30 minutes. After doing sudo -a -i /off and sudo -a -i /on in Terminal, IMMEDIATELY thereafter Spotlight works like a charm in Finder, and Finder only (searching Calendar, Outlook NO). Some hours later > Spotlight stops working in Finder.

Please go to the Eclectic Light website and download the free application called "Mints." (I have no affiliation with the developer.) In the Spotlight section of the Mints window, click Create Test, then Check Search, and when the daisy wheel disappears, Log Window. In the log window, click Get log. Paste the text that appears into an update of your original question. You can then click Delete Test and quit Mints.

Log from Mints added in original question

That’s a step in the right direction, but please don’t post screenshots of text. Delete the screenshot, then post the text into a code block. If you don’t have the text anymore, repeat the test. Thanks.

Welcome to Ask Different Poes! Please, please start an answer with all your investigations and things here. In the end it’s all part of how you will have a solid answer and comments are likely to be deleted …

Best to stop editing the question. Keep it short and clear - put all the complexity and work to get to an answer in the answer section .

Problem solved after using this command : sudo /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain u -domain s -domain l -v

Very interesting... I'm glad you sorted it out. Could you to rewrite your comment into an answer? That'd be a great help to others who have a similar issue. You can then accept your own answer.
